# Exclude value if they share the same ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this statement in my Access database:
It lists *Magazzino.Codice* from 2 tables and the relating quantities.

```
SELECT Magazzino.Codice, Magazzino.Qnt
FROM Magazzino
WHERE (((Magazzino.[Prossimo_arrivo]) Is Null) And ((Magazzino.Qnt)<30) And ((Magazzino.[Fascia_I])=True));
UNION ALL --Joins allowing duplicates
SELECT Magazzino.Codice, Magazzino.Qnt 
FROM  Magazzino
WHERE (((Magazzino.[Prossimo_arrivo]) Is Null) And ((Magazzino.Qnt)<10) And ((Magazzino.[Fascia_II])=True));
```

I wish to add a statement avoiding to list *Magazzino.Codice* if the same ID is present on a third table *Magazzino Grezzi*.
How can I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, simplify the logic assuming you don't want duplicates form this table:

```
SELECT m.Codice, m.Qnt
FROM Magazzino as m
WHERE m.[Prossimo_arrivo]) Is Null AND
      ( (m.Qnt < 30 AND m.[Fascia_I] = True) OR
        (m.Qnt < 10 AND m.[Fascia_II] = False) OR
      )
```

Then use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.Codice, m.Qnt
FROM Magazzino as m
WHERE m.[Prossimo_arrivo]) Is Null AND
      ( (m.Qnt < 30 AND m.[Fascia_I] = True) OR
        (m.Qnt < 10 AND m.[Fascia_II] = False) OR
      ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Magazzino_Grezzi as mg
                  WHERE mg.Codice = m.Codice
                 );
```

If you really want some rows to be duplicated (those that meet both conditions), then you can add the `NOT EXISTS` clause to both your subqueries.

Comment: "SELECT 1"? why "1"?

Comment: @Andrea . . . `EXISTS` checks for the existing of rows.  In general, rows need to have a column.  I find that `1` is the simplest value to type and accurate conveys the purpose of the code.